# file insta crashes blender everytime I open it

Tags: blend-files

My many hour project just started insta crashing blender, thought It might be because of the new version, but I went back and it's the same, I can open any other files. I think it got corrupted, is there any way to recover it?

Comment: Hi :). You can try *File > Recover > AutoSave* from a few hours ago ;). Or try to append the scenes/collections/objects into another file.

Comment: Try opening it from the console/terminal and see what (if any) error messages you get

Comment: It did make a crash txt altough I have no idea what it means but here it is  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GkeohjVbULv9w6C5ACHQ38dNGIVViFiBjgd6bgGUHcw/edit